# QVariant to QList with unkown list template parameter

Tags: c++, qt

I have several `QObject` classes, which may have `QList` properties, which store lists of `QObject` derived classes:

```cpp
class Object : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
    Q_PROPERTY(QList<AnotherQObject*> otherObjects READ otherObjects)
public:
    QList<AnotherQObject*> otherObjects() const;
}
```

`QList<AnotherObject*>` has of course been registered with `Q_DECLARE_METATYPE` and `qRegisterMetaType()`.

Now I want to read this property with Qt's meta object system. At the point where I want to read the list, I only care about (and know) the fact that the list contains pointers to objects, which have been derived from `QObject`, but not the exact type.

When I convert the property's `QVariant` to `QList<QObject *>`the list is empty.

```cpp
QObject *object = getObjectFromSomeWhere();
const char* propertyName = getPropertyNameFromSomeWhere(); // "otherObjects"

QVariant list = object->property(name);
QList<QObject *> objectList = list.value<QList<QObject *> >(); // empty

QList<AnotherQObject*> anotherObjectList = 
    static_cast<Object*>(object)->otherObjects() // not empty
```

Is it possible to access this list? Do you have other suggestions?

EDIT: Although I posted my solution, I would still love comments :-)

Comment: If you can change property to `QList< QVariant >` you can retrieve this list like that `QList< QVariant > objectList = object->property(name).toList()`. Casting from QVariant to QObject* is an ordinary thing.

Comment: I know. But I am writing a small library, which converts ordinary QObjects to JSON and vice versa, and (this is new:) allows links between related objects. I want the library user to be able to define his objects in the most intuitive way. Forcing him to model his relations as QVariantList is not what I want.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're using Qt 5.2 or higher there is a QSequentialIterable class that allows you to do this without the overhead of extra templates, modified macros, and additional registrations.

http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qsequentialiterable.html

If you have a `QList<T*>` stored in a `QVariant`, where T is derived from `QObject`, you can get a `QSequentialIterable` instance from the variant, which allows you to iterate over each item in the list as a `QVariant`. Then you can simply get the value of each item as a `QObject*`, adding to a `QList<QObject*>` as you go (make sure you test the assumption that the type is derived from `QObject`, though):

```
QList<QObject*> qobjectList;
if (variant.canConvert(QMetaType::QVariantList)) {
    QSequentialIterable iterable = variant.value<QSequentialIterable>();
    foreach (const QVariant& item, iterable) {
        QObject* object = item.value<QObject*>();
        if (object) { qobjectList.append(object); }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I think I solved the issue quite minimalistically. I created a template class, which can convert a `QVariant` containing a `QList<TemplateParameter *>` to `QList<QObject *>`.

Also I have a singleton, which stores a `QMap<int, Converter *>`, which maps from `QVariant::userType()` to the according converter.

This allows me to register each class, which I want to store in the properties as follows:

```cpp
VariantToObjectListConverter::instance()->registerConverter<AnotherQObject>();
```

I can then convert unknown `QVariants`:

```cpp
QVariant list = object->property("otherObjects");
QList<QObject *> objects = VariantToObjectListConverter::instance()->convert(variant);
```

This is the necessary code:

```cpp
class ConverterBase
{
public:
    virtual ~ConverterBase() {}
    virtual QList<QObject *> convert(const QVariant &variant) const = 0;
};

template<class Object>
class Converter : public ConverterBase
{
public:
    QList<QObject *> convert(const QVariant &variant) const
    {
        QList<Object *> list = variant.value<QList<Object *> >();
        QList<QObject *> result;
        Q_FOREACH(Object *object, list) result.append(object);
        return result;
    }
};

class VariantToObjectListConverter
{
public:
    Q_GLOBAL_STATIC(VariantToObjectListConverter, instance)

    ~VariantToObjectListConverter()
    {
        QHashIterator<int, ConverterBase *> i(m_converters);
        while (i.hasNext()) {
            i.next();
            delete i.value();
        }
    }

    template<class Object>
    void registerConverter()
    {
        QVariant v = QVariant::fromValue<QList<Object *> >(QList<Object *>());
        m_converters.insert(v.userType(), new Converter<Object>());
    }

    QList<QObject *> convert(const QVariant &variant) const
    {
        ConverterBase *converter = m_converters.value(variant.userType());
        if (!converter)
            return QList<QObject *>();

        return converter->convert(variant);
    }

private:
    QHash<int, ConverterBase *> m_converters;

    VariantToObjectListConverter() {}
};
```

I could now add a macro, which calls `registerConverter()`, `Q_DECLARE_METATYPE` and `qRegisterMetaType()`, so that the user only has to call

```cpp
REGISTER_TYPE(TypeName)
```